# How do I delete and/or move data in firebase once some time has completed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app allows users to post and sign up for different events that occur in the future. I'm stuck on finding a way to delete a certain event once it has completed. For example, a user creates an event that starts on October 8th and ends on October 10th. Once October 10th passes, I want the database to move or delete the event. I have no idea whether this is done with server-side code or with code within the app.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to trigger some action based on the passage of a point in time.  Your best option is to create a cron-like job that invokes a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) that periodically searches for and cleans up expired data.

Read this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) for more info, and see this [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron).

Answer (score 0):

On method is a scheduled job that essentially does:

```
delete from t
    where date 'now' > end_date;
```

I would vote for actually setting a flag on the event or moving it to another table -- deleting history always seems dangerous to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but in another way. U can try this. Actually, it is not an automated process. someone have to call or data when data arrived i checked the time and did this

```
//Moving to new url
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("newUrl")
                    .setValue(DATA);

            //Deleting from current url
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("oldUrl")
                    .child("keyOfYourData")
                    .removeValue();
```

did this before populating the data. hope in this way your job will be done.